# Importing an old ActionBarSherlock into Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock

I am importing an old project from Eclipse to Android Studio, and I'm stuck. I need to import ActionBarSherlock in version 4.1 to it, and I just don't know how. I've tried many solutions found on the Internet, but they were meant for newer versions of the library. There are no problems with importing version 4.4 as a module, but I specifically require 4.1, as the project uses it extensively, and its functions are missing in the newer versions. When I try to import it using the 'import module' all I get is a "Select modules to import".

Is there any way to make it work without reworking the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

From here you have gradle uri for ABS: `https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Gradle-Sample`

Next: create a new project in Android Studio, leave everything blank. Choose your supported SDK version blah blah and choose your expected packagename.

Add dependencies to new build.gradle. If you have jar files just copy them to `/lib` folder in your package hierarchy.

Copy your code base from Eclipse project to your Android Studio project. Make a build to see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this gradle sample is based on version 4.4 of ABS, so it doesn't have the functions this project requires.

Comment: AFAIK 4.4 is the latest version of ABS. What method do you require? And how you import ABS in your project?